# rosbridge: command not found

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to run https://github.com/lgsvl/lanefollowing example, I get an error after execute "docker-compose up drive" Error: "rosbridge: command not found"
Is this a problem from ROS2 "dashing" or rather lgsvl docker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370462/rosbridge:-command-not-found/) by [wkuznik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40032/wkuznik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Almost definitely an issue with their docker image. It's a wild guess, but it seems quite plausible that this is related to their latest commit, and in particular [this change](https://github.com/lgsvl/lanefollowing/commit/6e9a6e726d6c51bac2db3a01627f936c4fa68ef8#diff-dd2c0eb6ea5cfc6c4bd4eac30934e2d5746747af48fef6da689e85b752f39557L163).

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2021-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wkuznik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40032/wkuznik/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thanks. That's my guess too, I'll try to contact someone at LGSVL and when the problem is solved close this question.

**Comment by [wkuznik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40032/wkuznik/) on 2021-01-29**:
Problem solved: build new docker with ros-dashing-desktop (there is noch version 0.7.3-1 for dashing)

**Comment by [Klaus Schmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/68974/klaus-schmidt/) on 2021-01-30**:
I am having the same problem. Could you clarify how you built the new docker? I could not understand the comment in paranthesis.